# How to edit an ArcGIS Server WFS-T service in uDig?

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs, editing, wfs-t, udig

Now a straight forward workflow to do this is present in the below link.

http://udig.refractions.net/files/docs/uDigWalkthrough2.pdf

Point 3 of page 8 states to change to the ‘Edit Geometry’ tool from the tool bar.
[image]

But I can’t find this anywhere in the uDig interface.

[image]

What could I be missing?

Do note that the service added to uDig is a WFS-T service from ArcGIS Server and not GeoServer.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on your WFS layer?

Comment: @R.K. - Will permissions matter in at least getting the option to edit Geometry? Regardless, I have checked the permissions to confirm if they are correct and available.

Comment: ESRI web help seems to suggest so> *Specific WFS editors must be granted permissions on the SDE connection file in order to edit. http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#tutorial_wfst_service.htm

Comment: OK. The user with which I have connected to ArcSDE and added data to ArcMap in order to create a WFS service has the option to edit. It'll be this same user that'll be used by the client (through the ArcGIS WFS-T service), inorder to make the edits. Anything else I could check? Do you suspect there is a toolbar I may have missing? I've looked through all the available options in uDig to find the Toolbar the PDF refers to.

Comment: Did you enable transactions already?

Comment: Yes. The WFS service in ArcGIS Server has transactions enabled. I also tried using QGIS to edit the service, but the 'Toggle Geometry' tool required for editing in grayed out. All I need to do is edit the WFS-T service. But I can't seem to find a way to do that.